# vim - html in php files: how to change tab size for html only

Tags: php, html, vim, indentation

How to change the indent, tab size for HTML markup within PHP files? I dont want to change the indent size for php code. Desired tab sizes: HTML - 2, PHP - 4

so it looks like this:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Term</dt>
  <dd>
    <span>Definition</span>
  </dd>
  <dd>
<?php 
if ($a > $b) {
    echo $a;
    while ($c) {
        echo $d; 
    }
}
?>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: If I were you I'd consider using some kind of template engine instead of mixing html and php code altogether. (Of course if it is at all acceptable by the project limitations).

Comment: pkk, php already is a template language

Answer (score 0):

If this is to be done one time, I'd use (if there is not much code to be fixed) block-wise edit:

<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

`autocmd FileType html setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2`
`autocmd FileType php setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=4`

Add following code to your `.vimrc` file.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question.  The user has mixed HTML and PHP in the same buffer.  Even if a buffer could be two filetypes, there is still only one shiftwidth/tabstop variable per buffer.

Comment: @Conspicuous Compiler : yes :)

Comment: This answer was helpful for me, though, since I only needed it for one language. Thanks anyway @Kracekumar.